# Need help on nginx url rewriting

Tags: nginx, rewrite, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm having trouble rewriting this URL below:

https://domain-name.com/2020/10/title_of_article.html?id=1

into:

https://domain-name.com/0/1

- the year is unnecessary so it is removed/truncated/ignored
- the month is unnecessary so it is removed/truncated/ignored
- the title is also unnecessary, so it is removed/truncated/ignored
- an  additional "/0" is inserted right after domain name
- the "id=1" becomes the "/1"

to send into the application server.

Can someone help me to give me the regex (or whatever) for nginx to work? Should I be using the http rewrite module, or it can be done with plain settings? I'm stuck. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `rewrite` doesn't see anything after the `?`. You could use `$arg_id` for example: `if ($arg_id) { rewrite ^ /0/$arg_id? last; }`

Comment: Read. Learn and user: This: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ and this: 
https://www.cyberpunk.rs/nginx-rewrite-rules-for-pretty-urls

Comment: How do you intend to match a URL?